# finding an explicit formula from arctangent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Seems straight-forward but i can't get it right;

I have this implicit equation:
$$-2 \arctan{ \left( \frac{\sqrt{y-y^2}}{y} \right) } -x=c$$

where c is a constant.

I've to find the explicit equation for $y$...
The solution given in the book is $y= \sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}+c'\right)}$

where $c'$ is a function of $c$. However  my result is $y=\cos^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}+c'\right)}$
So..where's the mistake?

Comment: *So... where's the mistake?* - Probably nowhere, since $\cos(x)=\sin(x+\pi/2)$.

Comment: I get the same as you... with $c'=c/2$.

Comment: All of that comes from the differential equation:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-y^2}}dy-dx=0$$

Comment: when you  derive $y$ you get $-\cos(x/2+c')\sin(x/2+c')$ but if you substitute $y$ in the differential equation the equality isn't satisfied...instead if I use $y=\sin^2(x/2+c')$ the equation is satisfied

Comment: Just rewrite the equation like this:$$y'=\sqrt{y-y^2}$$ and then substitute

Answer (score 0):

just use $\sin(\theta + \pi/2)=\cos(\theta)$ and change slightly your $c'$ to get the same form as the book.